# Delete all data from all tables

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-3.5

Is there an elegant way to wipe all data in the database (removing every row from every table) without destroying the architecture and having to remove/read constraints?

I could just delete data from each table but this seems tedious. I've seen plenty of solutions for full on SQL implementations that make use of a stored procedure but obviously that functionality is not available to me. It's likely I won't be making this function available to end users of the product but it may be enabled for in-house testing purposes. As I stated I can do this manually so put this one down to curiosity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Since you want the db structure to remain intact including all relationships.
Hence, first delete all master data and then slave data.

your script should contain truncate queries in a specific order.

Otherwise what you can do is generate a entire db schema and keep it at your disposal. wheneever you need to empty the db, drop the db, recreate it :)

on how to generate schema for SQL-CE db..use [SQLCE-ToolBox](http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/)

also for more details about operation upon SQLCE db, I loved [this](http://erikej.blogspot.in/) blog, and most of the sqlce users all over the world :)

Comment: This sounds really useful and I have thought about creating the database (including some "default entries") on installation  rather than having to provide that in the installer however I wrote the database using [DataportConsole](http://www.primeworks-mobile.com/Products/DataPortConsole.html) to let me design the database using a diagram. Is there an easy to way to get a SQL CE scheme from an existing .SDF?

Comment: SQLCE TOOLBOX..this will give you options to generate schema with or without data for a .sdf file

Comment: That looks really useful but I only have access to VisualStudio2008

Comment: not a problem, there are bunch of tools in there for both SQLCE3.5 and SQLCE4.0, some of them are meant to integrate inside visual studio ide and some function stand alone.

Comment: The standalone version requires a version 4.0 database, same as the add in installer

Comment: so in that case go for command line utility : http://sqlcecmd.codeplex.com/ also, read the blog..link in the answer

Comment: Looked though the some of the posts on that blog (Favorited!) and found this which gave me the exact functionality I wanted in an easy to way use:

http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com/documentation

This allows SQL Server Management Studio to create a script of the Database scheme using an existing database.

Comment: great (meanwhile, try upgrading both the visual studio and sqlce version :D)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to some fantastic community help from [Manish Mishra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1495822/manish-mishra) the best solution is to delete the database file and rebuild the database using a schema. I found my way to an addin for SQL Server Management Studio called [ExportSqlCe](http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com/documentation) though {this blog](http://erikej.blogspot.co.uk/). If anyone else needs this functionality they will need [Microsoft SQL Sever Management Studio 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=7593) to be able to connect to a SQL CE 3.5 database.

Once connected to the database you can then create a database schema with this addon following these [instructions](http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com/documentation)

Answer (score 0):

if there are end users, then you can alternately use export option (in Express edition of
SQL Server it automatically avoids any data in the tables)

So using export option, you can easily create a replica of database including all the
things but no data in the tables

Comment: i guess, when you do export in sql server, all relationships are lost, that's the only way it can export, without caring about the dependencies

Comment: I have tested it, it retains all the things except the data as I have express edition installed

Answer (score 0):

I think of this: correct me if I did not understood your question:
you must iterate each table and then empty the table so a truncate table will just do the work.

You may get some help from 
http://how-to-code-net.blogspot.ro/2012/07/how-to-delete-all-tables-from-database.html
 so

```
DECLARE @TableName varchar(500)
DECLARE cur CURSOR
      FOR SELECT [name] FROM sys.tables WHERE type in ('u') 

      OPEN cur

      FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @TableName
      WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
      BEGIN
            EXEC('truncate TABLE ' + @TableName)
            --select @TableName
            FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @TableName
      END
      CLOSE cur
      DEALLOCATE cur
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: Well this will fail when there is a relationship between the tables.

Comment: I don' think SQL CE (3.5 at least) supports the TRUNCATE functionality

Comment: I once had to to the same think, but I used delete command; I run this code multiple times until it deleted all content (after first runs of course you get relationship errors)

Answer (score 0):

Little Late to the party but I found this while looking for something "elegant",

```
select 'DELETE FROM ' + name+';' from sys.objects where type = 'U';
```

Will generate a something that can be turned into a string. For me I use LINQPad and just copy and paste. Good little trick! Thanks http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1396480-392-1.aspx